# Passport oauth/token hashing the password

Tags: php, laravel-5, hash, oauth, laravel-passport

I'm trying to change the behavior of the oauth/token call from the passport package in laravel.
In my tests, I pass this:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
HOST: localhost:8080
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ikp...MDg4MzRjOTcifQ==
content-length: 41

grant_type=password&client_id=2&client_secret=dKhn6c8...tuECrPm1hjXN&username=test&password=123456&scope=*
```

and it works(I received the token with a 200 response).
But I believe that the correct would be to HASH the password, once that the password is already HASHed in the Server side, we should not send it visible in the request. 
Am I missing something here or what should I do to be able to send the HASHed password?

Thanks,
Joao

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has the following function for any values you want to hash:

```
bcrypt($value)
```

A good way to handle that would to create a setter method on your model that generates the password used:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value){

    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but how can I override the Passport routes?  And Why I would Hash it in the Server side, if what I want is to send the Hashed password from my app to the server. So, the Server would need to just get the password and compare with the DB (where is already hashed) and not actually hash it again.  It makes sense?